# Ridge and lasso regression missing?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

There is no implemented command to perform ridge or lasso regression?  I couldn't find it in the documentation. Might be there are add-on packages I am not aware of.

Comment: Related comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22218/multinomial-logistic-regression#comment69645_22224

Comment: None as far as I can tell. They certainly could be implemented, but it will take some programming work.

Comment: Also related, but not answered: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67630/27951

Comment: If in the next upgrade statistics is overhauled it would be a major boost for mathematica. Now it seems to be quite behind R even in major methods.

Comment: Have you seen [RLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html)?

Comment: Yes, I tried a few simple things on it. I will look more closely.

Comment: Jonathan Kinlay wrote a notebook that he published a few years ago on generalized regression; however, official support would be a good thing. http://www.jonathankinlay.com/Articles/Generalized%20Regression/Generalized%20Regression.pdf